# Is it possible to configure nginx to serve the directory from which it is run, rather than a hardcoded path?

Tags: nginx

Normally we point nginx at a directory by using the `root` directive in `conf/nginx.conf`.

However, I am wondering if I can put something for that option so that nginx will always serve the directory that I am currently working in (that is, the output of `pwd`) instead of the fixed path. I have tried setting `.` as the root, but that does not seem to work.

I am running `nginx` as a non-root user, serving requests at a port greater than 1024.

Answer (score 0):

If you use directive `root .;`, the real path of root directory is `/<nginx_prefix_path>/.`.

You can use command `sbin/nginx -p $(pwd) -c /path/to/nginx.conf` to start nginx,
in which case `<nginx_prefix_path>` is changed to your current working directory.

BTW, command `sbin/nginx -h` shows the default `<nginx_prefix_path>`:

```
-p prefix     : set prefix path (default: /usr/local/nginx/)
```